# Cannot get MapView to Zoom in on current location - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I have tried all day on this - seems it should be simple - but I cannot get the MapView to zoom in on the current location.

Using "Apple" in the simulator for the location just for testing - I don't get any errors and it runs - but the view just stays at a full picture of the USA with a blue dot - in California representing the Apple location.  Any help is appreciated in advance!

Code as follows:

```
import MapKit
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,    MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!


func createLocationManager () {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone


}

func locationManager (manager:CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]!) {
    if let firstlocation = locations.first as? CLLocation {
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(firstlocation.coordinate, animated: true)
        let region = MKCoordinateSpanMake (1000,1000)

    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

      }
```

Comment: Are you calling you createLocationManager() method? Otherwise you are not setting the delegate.

Comment: Onato - this is going to sound like a stupid question - (and it probably is).  I thought it automatically called when the mapviewcontroller executes.  I have a tableviewcontroller - that when the row is selected it takes you to the map (and this mapviewcontroller.swift with the code above in it) that is supposed to show your current location (zoomed in of course) - how do I get the method called under this set up?

Comment: Nope, no magic here. You are repeating some of this code in your viewDidLoad. Just replace this with `createLocationManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Debug->Location->City Bicycle Ride` in the simulator. This will give you continual updates.

Also make sure you are setting the locationManager's delegate.

Comment: no change - I am trying but may need you to spell it out for me - I have a couple of other views doing the same thing - and this is hindering some key functionality for me.  Thanks for your patience